# Как сохранить данные из баз SQLIte в разные файлы?

Tags: c#, sqlite

В папке есть несколько файлов с базой **sqlite**
мне нужно прочитать каждый файл и записать именно из каждой папки те данные в новый файл.

На данный момент я делаю так прохожусь циклом `for` по папке, делаю подключение к каждой базе и собираю данные в `List<string>` Затем просто все данные записываю в один файл ( но мне нужно каждый по отдельности записать ).

```
public static void Save()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < GetBase.Count; i++)
  using (var con = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={GetBase[i]};Version=3;"))  Connect.Open();
  using (var text = new SQLiteCommand("Commanda", con))
  using (SQLiteDataReader reader = text.ExecuteReader())
  // Читаю базы
  while (reader.Read())
  {
     // Тут заношу все данные в список List<string> 
     Name = (string)reader["StaticName"],
  }
  // Далее просто сохраняю всё в файл.
}
```

Мне нужно как-то реализовать сохранение данных которые я читаю по отдельности в каждый файл

Comment: В файлы какого формата вы хотите записывать? Текстовые? SQLite?

Comment: @Bulson, Текстовые. .txt - формат

Comment: `StringBuilder` - для формирования строк из данных, `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` - для создания имени файла ну, или сами напишите генератор имен файлов, `System.IO.File.WriteAllText()` - для записи строк в файл.

Comment: @Bulson, Наверное Вы меня не так поняли, кажется я плохо описал ситуацию :(  Мне нужно при чтение каждой таблицы из файлов сохранить по отдельности все данные, например я читаю первый файл, его данные нужно сохранить в отдельный файл, после читается другой файл базы его нужно записать в отдельный файл, и.т.д читаем первый файл базы данных и записываем в отдельный файл.  А у меня получается всё в одном цикле и читается сразу все файлы и я не знаю как сделать по отдельности.